# How do I correctly add the file input stream to my Firebase JSON file

Tags: java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

My JSON file resides in the projects root folder, I have correctly set up the dependencies and now I'm trying to add the JSON file Using the instructions as provided by Firebse themselves [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Here is the code from my main java file:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Random;

 public class Climate {
    public static void main(String [] args){
          FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");


          FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://*retracted*.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

          FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
 }
```

this is how it look in the IDE [image]

and this is the message under next to it: [image]

It says file not found but the file is there i assure you, am I being really dumb here, please excuse my incompetence I'm new to firebase... any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround that statement by "try and catch" or use throws exceptions.

```
 public class Climate {
    public static void main(String [] args){
          FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://*retracted*.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Climate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                serviceAccount.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Climate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```